# Speed of value change

Tags: c#, string, integer, counter, comparator

I have a C# code, that receive a data over Serial from a pressure transducer in Bar by newline one per second, like: 
0.25
0.69
1.28
3.16
0.26
etc

I need to known the intensity of change in one second, for example:
0.25
0.69
The sensor read a pressure increase of 0.44 bar/s
Next will be:
0.69
1.28
The sensor read a pressure increase of 0.59 bar/s

My code looks like:

```
string sensor1 = group1.Split(':')[0];
string sensor2 = group2.Split(':')[0];
int diffsens = int.Parse(sensor1) - int.Parse(sensor2);
label35.Invoke(new Action(() => label35.Text = sensor1));
label37.Invoke(new Action(() => label37.Text = sensor2));
counter++;
int timerS = counter;
```

So howto read the change of sensor1 in a time unit and compare the intensity change compared to last measurement?

Comment: You can try using [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.1). Put started one in a field like(i assume) your `counter` is and save `ElapsedMilliseconds` to separate field and comapre then overwrite.

Comment: By the way, the word you are looking for is *derivative* (often written as *dx/dt* where *x* is your measured value).  That's the mathematical term for what you describe as "the intensity of change in one second".  If you want to find out what the term is in another language, consult any introductory calculus book in that language.  As to your question.  I don't follow your code.  You are splitting on ":", but I don't see any ":" in your input - you describe the input as separated by newlines.  Does your input include time stamps?  Or is it just as you show?

Comment: Why are you parsing sensor1 and sensor2 to an int and not to a float? Aren't they supposed to be the pressure values received from the serial? If the serial is receiving a new value each second, as you state in the beginning of the question, wouldn't be enough to enqueue the values on a queue and, on each new data arrival, given the queue contains at least 2 items, dequeue the first value and substract it from the second (without dequequing the 2nd item, of course)? I said queue, but an ObservableCollection could also be used to be notified of each new value coming in.